# How to open and edit a file(doc,pdf,excel etc) in browser window using zk?

Tags: java, zk

I have a application which is created on ZK Framework , i want to give user a functionality where user can open a saved file in edit mode and then again saved the changed in database can any one know which API can help me to do this?

Comment: I have edited my Question.Please refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Google Apps** to do so and set Google Docs to edit your DOC, PDF or even XLS extension files. For more help on setting it up, feel free to ask again. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're posing doesn't have a simple answer, unfortunately.

There are two general approaches you could take..

The low hanging fruit is to provide an interface for the user to download a file and upload it after they make edits using whichever editing software they choose / is appropriate.

The other approach would be to provide a GUI to edit files. Regardless of the web framework you are using, this is a daunting task to say the least. As @userRandom mentioned, this is a large part of what Google Drive (formerly Google Docs) is attempting to solve.. but even Google's solution is not perfect and very much a work in progress.

**I would strongly suggest evaluating the scope of your project before proceeding.**
If you choose to move forward, consider a simple solution that works for .txt files. Then, consider how you might handle .doc files. Then, PDF files, XLS files, etc.

Folks here will be able to answer specific questions.